# Django model, default records

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a beginner in Django, and I am learning models for now.
I have two tables in the backend, one a child of another (1-to-many relationship).
So far, so good.

What I want to do is set Django, so that if a record is created in the parent table, the child table will automatically create 3 records.

How do I program this?
Thanks.

Comment: if you want to it basically happen always (not under special circumstances) then there are two ways: [override the `save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) and using signals, eg [the `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save)

Comment: Hi Anentropic, thanks for the quick response.  In the examples you provide, all of the save overrides use the super call against the same class.  how do I use the save against another class?  Or is that just a straight stick save call? Thanks

Comment: Yes you still need the super call to save the parent instance, but then you can add any extra code you want to create your child models

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in something like this:

```
# ... other imports ...
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save

class Parent(models.Model)

  # this decorator & this method go inside your model
  @staticmethod
  def create_children(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
      for x in range(3):

        # I'm assuming you want the child to be linked to the parent immediately.  
        # You can set any other attributes you want here too, of course.
        child = Child(parent = instance)
        child.save()

pre_save.connect(Parent.create_children, Parent)
```

Note that in the pre_save.connect() call, you can call any [SomeClass].[SomeMethodOfThatClass] (this is the first argument) on the save of some other class (this is the second argument).  In practice, though, I don't think I've actually ever done that, and I'm not sure that you need to do that here.